# Multiple inputs with the same name on Netlify forms

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, netlify

I'm having problem with Netlify Forms. Basically I'm having a form with multiple inputs, each one with a unique "name" attribute.
This is my TextInput component:

```
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core"
import * as styles from "../styles/TextInput.module.css"

const TextInput = ({ label }) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      label={label}
      name={label}
      id="outlined-size-normal"
      variant="outlined"
      size="small"
      className={styles.input}
    />
  )
}

export default TextInput
```

And this is how I'm using it in a single contact form:

```js
import React from "react"
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core"
import { TextInput } from "../components/"
import * as styles from "../styles/Contato.module.css"

const Contato = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.formContainer}>
      <form
        name="contato"
        form-name="contato"
        method="POST"
        data-netlify="true"
        action="/obrigado/contato"
        className={styles.fullPageForm}
      >
        <h1 className={styles.formTitle}>Formulário de contato</h1>
        <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contato" />
        <TextInput label="Nome" />
        <TextInput label="Email" />
        <TextInput label="Telefone" />
        <TextInput label="Assunto" />
        <TextField
          label="Mensagem"
          name="Mensagem"
          id="outlined-multiline-static"
          variant="outlined"
          multiline
          rows={6}
          className={styles.textArea}
        />
        <button className={styles.sendMessageBtn}>Enviar Mensagem</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Contato;
```

The request is sent correctly to Netlify, but when they parse it, all the entries have the same key/label name:
[image]

I've already tried all my debugging ideas. Am I missing anything?

edit1: This is the request the browser sends to netlify form endpoint:
[image]
Notice how the key/value pairs are send to netlify

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, I had missing this line of code (which is necessary for Netlify to process the form): `<input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />`

Comment: Ah yes I see thanks!